# Discrete Fourier transform in a multidimensional space

Tags: fft, fourier-transform

I want to measure the frequencies at which a point oscillates in a multidimensional space, let's take the example of a point on a 2d-surface.
For now, I naïvely split the signal in two, along the cartesian coordinates, and compute the two FFTs separately. This approach could work but seems to be arbitrary and may loose relevant information. Is there a **canonical** way to perform the **frequency analysis in multidimensional space** ?

*It is **unrelated** to 2D FFT. I take a vector of size 2*T and 2D FFT is concerned by plain T^2 data, like images.*

---

Here is an example where halving the signal along the polar coordinates seems better than along the cartesian coordinates.

The data used, a point evolving in 2D,

[image: Evolution of a point in 2D]

And here is the FFTs for

1. The cartesian coordinates x and y (a bit noisy)
2. The polar coordinates theta and rho (very clear)

[image: FFT for the previous data]

*edit after Mohammad's comment about velocity*

And here is the FFT for the velocity vector (very noisy, and looses information in high frequencies)
[image: FFT for the velocity]

Comment: By 'frequency' here, I take it to mean you wish to measure "The rate of displacement of my point in axis x, y, z, etc etc", correct? From physics, then you want to measure the 'speed', which is the rate of change in displacement. So why not simply take the first derivative of your x-displacement measure, same for the y, square them, add them, and take the square root? This then gives you the euclidean rate of displacement at each point. You want to measure velocity it seems. I do not see how the DFT is relevant.

Comment: I don't know if "frequency" is the right term in multidimension, but the DFT is definitely what I want for the problem restricted in 1D. I want to measure the amplitudes of oscillations of my signal, for low frequencies as well as for the high frequencies.

Comment: Ok, so you want a frequency decomposition of the rate of change of displacement. So to me, that is, (as you have said), a DFT of your _velocity_ vector, which is the same thing as saying, "I want a frequency decomposition of my rate of change vector". In that case, take the first derivatives as I suggested for every dimension, and DFT the results. Then, I would simply add the resulting DFT bins together across the dimensions.

Comment: This might works, and I will try on my applications. But I continue to think this will loose some information, at least the constant terms.

Comment: I've edited my question to take into account the DFT of the velocity vector. It seems to capture the low frequencies, but is very noisy in the high frequencies.

Comment: Emile, Your high frequency points are not 'noisy' - they are what they are. You have a lot of high-frequency oscillations of your point. Physically, this means your point almost never sits still.

Comment: I've just done some experiments with the FFT on the velocity. I've concluded that I basically amplificate the high-frequency, but the process is still able to recover the useful information. See this plot as an example, http://i.imgur.com/ZgFQVSL.png. If anyone knows the reasons...

Comment: Is this point moving around in a circle?  Does it make sense to express your position as a complex signal x+iy and then use a single FFT on that?  Your positive and negative frequency spectra will not be symmetrical for complex input.

Comment: Good point :) Is FFT(x+iy) equivalent to compute the sum of FFT(x)+iFFT(y) ?